# React Material Data Grid: Sorting a currency field

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

I am passing in rows of financial data to a React MUI Data Grid component, however, as a currency symbol exists within the cell data the default sorting function is not working. Is there anyway I can ignore the currency symbol when applying sort?

```
[
  {id: 0, cpa: '£20', cpl: '£0', revshare: '0%', startDate: '02/03/2022'}
  {id: 1, cpa: '£10', cpl: '£0', revshare: '0%', startDate: '02/02/2022'}
]


<DataGrid
  disableSelectionOnClick
  headerHeight={65}
  rowHeight={70}
  autoHeight
  className={classes.root}
  rows={displayRowData(rowsData)}
  columns={columns}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom `sortComparator` in the columns of your `<DataGrid/>`.
Assuming your currency symbol is always the first character, your `cpa` column definition would look like this:

```
  const columns = [
    ...
    {
      field: "cpa",
      headerName: "cpa",
      sortComparator: (a: string, b: string) =>
        Number(a.slice(1)) - Number(b.slice(1)),
    },
    ...
  ];
```

For more information regarding sorting I would recommend checking out the [official documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/sorting/).